# How might we formally define the concatenation of two strings?

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, context-free-grammar, formal-grammar, analysis-of-algorithms

### Below we offer some definitions of string.

### How would you mathematically define the concatenation of strings?

---

**The $\mathtt{HELLO\ WORLD}$ Example**

> $“\mathtt{HELLO}” + “\mathtt{\ }” + \mathtt{WORLD}” = “\mathtt{HELLO\ WORLD}”$

---

**The $\mathtt{HOW\ ARE \ YOU}$ Example**

> $\mathbb{WS} = \{ “\mathtt{HOW}”, “\mathtt{ARE}”, “\mathtt{YOU}” \}$
>
> $\sum_{\sigma \in \mathbb{WS}}^{\text{}} \sigma  = “\mathtt{HOW\ ARE \ YOU}”$

---

### Definitions of *Unicode String*

**Fuzzy Definition of Unicode String**

> $\require{enclose}$    $\require{cancel}$ A **string** is function whose inputs are numbers and the outputs are [Unicode characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) such that indexing begins at $1$, and we have $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\} \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\sigma(-|k|) = \sigma(+|k|)}$

**Edit**

I meant to write $\sigma(n-|k|) = \sigma(|k|)$ where $n$ is the minimum non-negative zalen integer from $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\sigma(n-|k|) = \mathtt{null}$

**Detailed Definition of Unicode String**

> For any mapping $\sigma$ from the zalen integers $\mathbb{Z}$ without zero to the set of all Unicode character $\mathbb{U}$ we say that $\sigma$ is a ***string***
>
> > if and only if
>
> There exists $n$ element of the zalen without zero such that:
>
> > if
> >
> > > the absolute value of $n$ is less than or equal to the absolute value of $m$
> > > then
> > > for any $k$ element of the set of all zalen without zero,
> > >
> > > > all of the following:
> > > >
> > > > > if
> > > > >
> > > > > > $-|n|$ is less than or equal to $k$
> > > > > > and
> > > > > > $k$ is less than or equal to the absolute value of $n$
> > > > > > then
> > > > > > $\sigma(k)$ not equal to $\mathtt{null}$
> > > > >
> > > > > if
> > > > >
> > > > > > $k$ strictly less than $-|n|$
> > > > > > or
> > > > > > $k$ strictly greater than $+|n|$
> > > > > > then
> > > > > > $\sigma(k) = \mathtt{null}$

Additionally, $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}, \sigma(-|n|) = \sigma(+|n|)$

**Mostly Symbolic Representation of the Definition of Unicode String**

> $\forall \sigma \subseteq (\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}) \times (\mathbb{U}) \in $ the set of all finite-length ***strings***
>
> > $\iff$
>
> $\forall z, z^{\prime} \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\} \land \forall \mathtt{ch}, \mathtt{ch}^{\prime} \in \mathbb{U} (\sigma(z) = \sigma(z^{\prime})) \implies (\mathtt{ch} = \mathtt{ch}^{\prime})$
>
> $\land$
>
> $\exists n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\} \backepsilon$
>
> > > $|n| \leq |m|$
> > > $\implies$
> > > $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$,
> > >
> > > > all of the following:
> > > >
> > > > > > $-|n| \leq k \leq +|n|$
> > > > > > $\implies$
> > > > > > $\sigma(k) \neq \mathtt{null}$
> > > > >
> > > > > > $k < -|n|$ or $k > +|n|$
> > > > > > $\implies$
> > > > > > $\sigma(k) = \mathtt{null}$

---

## Mostly Wordy Definition of Subsequence

The question was, how would you define concatenation of strings.

However, it might be easiest to copy, paste, and edit a definition for subsequence.

> For any two strings $\sigma$ and $\Sigma$, $\sigma$ is a ***sub-sequence*** of $\Sigma$ if and only if for every $z$ element of the zalen integers there exists  $K$ element of the zalen integers such that $k$ is less than or equal to $K$ and $\sigma(k)$ is $\Sigma(K)$

---

## Mostly symbolic Definition of Subsequence

The question was, how would you define concatenation of strings.

However, it might be easiest to copy, paste, and edit a definition for subsequence.

> For any two strings $\sigma$ and $\Sigma$, $\sigma$ is a ***sub-sequence*** of $\Sigma \iff \forall z \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\} \exists K \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}: k \leq K  \land \sigma(k) = \Sigma(K)$

Comment: AFAIK it would be more usual to say that the concatenation of HELLO and WORLD is HELLOWORLD, not HELLO WORLD.

Comment: @David You are correct. I forgot about the space character. In future communication, it might help to write "as far as I know" instead of writing "AFAIK". The set of people on planet earth who understand the meaning of the string `AFAIK` is a proper subset of the people on planet earth who understand the string `as far as I know`.

Comment: It is the first hit on a Google search.  In any case the subset you refer to is a pretty large proper subset (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

If $\Sigma$ is a finite set of alphabets then we can define a string recursively as:

1. $\lambda$ (the empty string) is a string;
2. $\forall\; x \in \Sigma$, $x$ is a string;
3. If $a$ and $b$ are strings then so is $ab$.

You can add the white-space character(s) in $\Sigma$ if you wish.